# Can we build WPF application in .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

As we know there is no direct approach to create WPF application in MAUI, is there any other way around to create WPF applications using .NET MAUI ?

Comment: Duplicate of closed question https://stackoverflow.com/q/72259515/5114784

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg it got closed

Comment: Because it made no sense. You know you can't build a WPF application on MAUI.

Comment: @Clemens Xamarin Forms supports WPF right ?

Comment: On the other hand, a WPF application [can use](https://swharden.com/csdv/maui.graphics/quickstart-wpf/) MAUI graphics but I suspect this is not what you wanted (because it is just drawing, not adding controls and such). MAUI graphics is [supported](https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics#supported-platforms) on many platforms in multiple environments, including WPF, WinForms, Xamarin, etc.

Comment: @Clemens in this link they mentioned MAUI supports WPF https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/create-your-first-net-maui-app-with-microsoft-mvp-codrina-merigo-webinar-show-notes.aspx

Comment: That (non-Microsoft) blog answer is wrong. WPF is a Windows-only technology. If your goal is to run on **Windows desktops**, then [Upgrade WPF App to .NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-wpf-framework). If your goal is to run on **multiple platforms**, then there is no "easy" answer - Rewrite for Maui, preserving as much xaml and c# as possible.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/72259515/5114784, but I can't mark it as such since that question has been deleted. I'll repeat my answer here.

.NET MAUI does not support WPF. As seen on the [Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms), Windows is supported through [Win UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/apps/winui/winui3/) for Windows 11 and Windows 10 version 1809 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

WPF is good for desktop, while .NET MAUI is good for mobile. However, if you need to target both device types, you can reuse your business logic and XAML knowledge: [From Desktop to Mobile — Why .NET MAUI is Straightforward for WPF Developers](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/wpf/archive/2023/03/21/from-desktop-to-mobile-why-net-maui-is-straightforward-for-wpf-developers.aspx)

Comment: this link doesn't appear to function